# Connection string for Excel 2019

Tags: excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I am using OLEDB.12.0 for Excel 2007 and I used

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Now that we have upgraded to Office 2019, what should be the connection string to be used? And apart from this, should I install any drivers ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to change anything there.

Comment: I assumed since the excel version is now upgraded, the extended properties will also change. Isn't that the case usually?

Comment: No, only when the file formats change. The xls format was Excel 8 (BIFF) but Office version 8 was Office 97. That connection string didn't change until the new compressed formats came along.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, when i tried to execute with the same connection string, I am getting the error 3706 ,  "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. " Any idea on this error or how to resolve it?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without digging on your specific setup but you are probably using the 64bit version rathe than the 32bit one. Sometimes it may be the other way around and in theory you can have both installed. It's called DLL (or version) hell. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from connectionstrings.com

> **Xlsx files**
>
> Connect to Excel 2007 (and later) files with the Xlsx file extension.
> That is the Office Open XML format with macros disabled.
>
> ***Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data***
> ***Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel***
> ***12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";***
>
> "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.
>
> *Source: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/*